# using an array as a condition in an if loop (CONTINUED)

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

First and foremost, I'm brand new to python and quite new to coding in general.

I'm trying to have a for loop run through an array of arrays, `a`, but only run the loop at specific points in `a`. `b` in this code is an array such as `[0,9,14,36]`. In my previous question, I was trying to have the code run while excluding an array such as `b`, but I'm trying to do the opposite here. I tried `if not any` and that didn't work, as well as a few other things. Nothing has run so far. Any help would be grealy appreciated.

```
for numi,i in enumerate(a):
    if any(v in b for v in i):
        for numj,j in enumerate(a):
            if any(v in b for v in j):
                angle=(np.arccos(np.dot(i,j)/(np.linalg.norm(i)*np.linalg.norm(j))))*180/(np.pi)
                print(angle)
            else: 
                continue
    else:
        continue
```

a sample of `a`:

```
[-2.736 -0.466 -2.248] 
[-3.373 -2.93 -1.288]
[-0.765 -3.666 1.123]
...
```

Comment: What would you suggest I change? I'm not sure how to make my question more specific as I'm not very familiar with all the terminology yet.

Comment: For starters, see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Again, read through the posting guidelines in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the built-in `all` instead of `any`. That seems to be what you're asking for.

Also please reserve the use of the letters `i,j,k` for indices. Use other letters for other variables. Typically:

```
for i,a in enumerate(v):
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Unforunately, `all` did not work. I'm using visual code studio as my IDE and it's not even giving me an error to work with. I think the problem may be less related to my code and more related to my logic.